# reactiveValues cannot be used to render output

Tags: r, shiny

I'm developing a shiny app using reactive value, of course. However, I'd like to explore the use of `reactiveValues` to test my understanding of the concept. My design is to create a `dt` container of reactive values, e.g. `data`, `cols`, `rows`; so that I can save shiny `input$file` uploaded data to `dt$data`; also I'd use `checkboxGroupInput` to display the columns of the data, which is saved as `dt$cols`, and let users to select columns and then render data table of `dt$data[dt$cols]`. Here's the code I used:

```
dt <- reactiveValues()
observeEvent(input$uploadbutton, {

       file <- input$file
       req(input$file)
       f <- read.csv(file$datapath, header = TRUE)
       dt$data <- f

       # get the col names of the dataset and assign them to a list
       cols <- mapply(list, names(dt$data))

       # update columns ui under columnscontrol div
       updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "columns", "Select Columns:", choices = cols, selected = cols)
})

observeEvent(input$columns, { dt$cols <- input$columns  })

output$datatbl <- DT::renderDataTable(
   dt$data[dt$cols], rownames = FALSE,
   # column filter on the top
   filter = 'top', server = TRUE,
   # autoWidth
   options = list(autoWidth = TRUE)
)
```

The code didn't work, I was thrown with the error of "undefined columns" when `dt$data[dt$cols]` is called. However, the above works fine if I only use reactive value `dt2 <- eventReactive(input$columns, { f <- dt$data[input$columns], f })` and then call `dt2()` in `renderDataTable()`. I wonder what's wrong with the use of the variables in `reactiveValues`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you upload the file, the instruction `dt$data <- f` will then trigger the `renderDataTable` which uses `dt$data`. This happens before `dt$cols <- input$columns` is called therefore `dt$cols`is NULL and `dt$data[dt$cols]` throws an error.

You can try with `isolate` :

```
isolate(dt$data)[dt$cols]
```

Comment: Another option is to start the `renderDataTable` command with `req (dt $data, dt $cols)`, which prevents `renderDataTable` from executing until the two required elements have "truthy" values

Comment: I first thought of using `req` @Benjamin, as it would prevent the NULL. But when you upload a new file with different columns there will still be a problem... Unless you also set `data$cols` right after reading the file. It's always difficult to react to several events in the right order.

Comment: @HubertL Your solution worked for me. Now I `renderDataTable` of `isolate(dt$data[dt$cols])` successfully following the change of `input$columns` and then the call of `dt$cols <- input$columns`. I do agree with you `req` cannot be used here as it can't help `dt$cols` to match up the columns of `dt$data` if any change made after the first time.